# Redirect all other requests to index page

Tags: node.js, jwt, koa

From https://github.com/koajs/jwt

```
app.use(jwt({ secret: 'shared-secret' }));
```

is used to secure the followed routes.

Question: How can I specify it only for defined set of routes and make the redirect to a static html page if no path is matched.

My current code:

```
app
    .use(indexRouter.routes())
    .use(jwt({secret: conf.secret }))
    .use(protectedRouter.routes())
    .use((ctx: any)=> ctx.body='My html page'); <-- this doesn't work because it is considered a protected route
```

Expected pseudo-code:

```
app.use(indexRouter.routes())
        .use(protectedRouter.routes(), jwt({secret: conf.secret }))
        .use((ctx: any)=> ctx.body='My html page');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since my protected routes are all under 'api' route, I did it like this:

```
.use(indexRouter.routes())
.use(async (ctx: Context, next: () => void) => {
  if (ctx.path.substring(0,5) === '/api/'){
    await next();
  }else{
    ctx.body='My html page'
  }
})
.use(jwt({secret: conf.secret}))
.use(protectedRouter.routes());
```